# Is it better to ship WAR with class files of JSPs, instead of JSPs themselves?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, deployment, architecture

If we can make Tomcat/Jasper compile JSPs using an ANT task, wouldn't it better to ship the WAR with pre-compiled JSPs as class files, rather than JSPs themselves?

That way, we are not tied down with Weblogic/Webshere JSP compilation issues. All that they would get are 'class' files.

I think this would need that the "jsp" servlet would have to be turned off somehow. And the Spring/Struts Servlet will have to enabled to handle 'jsp' extension.

What do you think? And what is the more commonly done thing in other production environments?

Comment: I had created one more Q similar to this one. Looks like "standard practice" is to ship JSPs files http://stackoverflow.com/q/10414823/233306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally say no it's not better.  I think it's too much trouble to go through, then just packaging the ear/war up and shipping.

If you're JSP's aren't compiling in production, and are compiling locally or in QA then you have other issues that need to be solved as well.

Comment: In past I have seen an issue where a particular Websphere couldn't compile the JSP, because of some taglib issue. We can't really protect ourselves from such unpredicatable things.  Nowadays people are expecthing support for things like Caucho, resin, etc.

Comment: I think the issue at the point had something to do backward compatibility with jsp-api 1.x or 2.x . It was a jar that we never bothered about, becase Weblogic just gave it to us.

Comment: If you have compile issues due to random things like support for Caucho, resin, or backward compatibility issues, why wouldn't you expect runtime errors for those issues as well?  I know sometimes you need libraries at compile that you don't necessarily need at run, but I'd still expect issues in these cases.

Comment: If I generate class files using Jasper, and then ship Jasper Jar in my WEB-INF/lib, there won't be any run-time issues. No ? As of now, I think JSP handling is the only thing that prevents me from determining whether an application will run on any random server. That is the reason why I am thinking of this approach.  Using this approach, all that I will need is Servlet 2.5 from webserver, and I will be fine.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You have to be sure that all the libraries go with you.  Once you compile a class, there's nothing to guarantee that all the libs you need exist until it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Compilation of JSPs has the following advantages.

- You are sure it can be compiled, i.e. no surprises at runtime.
- You save some time when user arrives to the JSP first time.

I think that the first advantage is important, the second one is not so important. I personally do not care if the first and only first user will wait additional second or two while the jsp is being compiled. But I care very much the now user will never get compilation error when he/she is using my application.

I think that it is enough compile JSPs during build just for validation and not pack produced `.class` files with your application. But distributing the `.class` files is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled JSP are not portable across containers. They extend runtime specific classes. You can always try to embed your own JSP implementation, but that's a different problem.

Comment: What about class files of the compiled JSPs? If I generate class files using Jasper, and then ship Jasper Jar in my WEB-INF/lib, there won't be any run-time issues. No ?

Comment: Potentially not. But then you're embedding the JSP implementation, as I mentioned. Can't speak to what ever other issues may occur. It may be just that simple.