# Are JSPs generally shipped as .jsp files , pre-compiled Java files or pre-compiled class files?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, deployment, war

Is there a 'standard' practice for packaging JSPs when preparing WAR for Production Env?

Are they included as ".jsp" files?

Or are they included as pre-compiled Java files, or pre-compiled class files?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your previous question found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400561/is-it-better-to-ship-war-with-class-files-of-jsps-instead-of-jsps-themselves)?

Comment: Well, kind of, but I wanted to ask a new one specifically about "standard practice"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Servelts/JSP spec says nothing about precompiling JSPs making this feature **specific to container implementation**. You can pre-compile for a specific container, say for Tomcat or for WebLogic and you will surely find Ant tasks to do so.

Generally, when you package your app you know your target. If it's more than one container (say you package a downloadable product) then your only option is to package raw JSPs into your WAR file. That said, however, when you're in development and/or testing you certainly can pre-compile as part of your build process to a) validate that your JSPs are correct and b) speed up the start-up time. You can even have your Eclipse do it for you if you need that extra validation step as you are building your software.

I don't think there's an industry practice to do one way or the other. From what I have experienced the JSPs are usually packaged "raw" (not pre-compiled) for deployment and distribution but are pre-compiled as part of build/test process.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb that if its compile in Tomcat (or maybe Jetty), then it "will" compile in any App Server?  I wish there was matrix that one could refer to.

Comment: @rk2010 I would say no. I clearly remember from five or seven years back how Websphere had some issues with how how they handle classloading or something that made JSPs pre-compile fine for Weblogic but fail pre-compilation under the WebSphere. I don't have those examples handy so I can't back it up with an evidence but don't take these things for granted. Better safe than sorry. Assume it doesn't work until you have proven otherwise, or don't pre-compile :)

Comment: but, isn't pre-compiling the 'safer' option?

Comment: @rk2010 I remembered that the issue with the WebSphere had something to do with the taglibs. The thing is that you have to compile with the JSP compiler of your target container, as if it had compiled it "normally" on first JSP use. That's what makes this whole pre-compilation process specific to container implementation. It is safer to precompile, you would know that your pages do, in fact, compile, but then it locks you for that container you compiled for. Maybe even for that specific version. It's your call at the end of the day.

Comment: @PavelVeller Thanks. So, I think the standard practice is to just put the JSPs as-is.  But perhaps a better thing to do, would be to have an  Ant  to compile JSPs into java files, just to know if the JSPs will compile in Production.  Perhaps - one should should write "one Ant Task per Container" that will be compile JSPs using compilers of each of the "certified" Servers.  If these tasks succeed,  then we should create the "WAR" with plain JSPs in it.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, they are just shipped in the WAR as .jsp files. The application server will automatically compile the .jsp into a class file. See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro4.html) for more info on the jsp life cycle.

Comment: but I have seen more than once instance ..where JSP didn't compile in production. The one example I remember.. was that one of the Production App servers didn't support backward compantibility for some specific JSP tag issue (attribute vs variable)

Comment: Well, I would say that's more an issue with testing and knowing your production environment than with the jsp's themselves.

Comment: I don't know..  most environments I have seen have only one App Server (vendor/version) available to Dev/QA.

Comment: Ideally, you should have a testing environment identical to your production environment, but I realize that is usually cost-prohibitive.

Comment: Not to mention QA might not test all Test Cases across all the 4-5 App Servers (more?) that are "certified" for a given application.

Answer (score 0):

They are packaged as .jsp files itself. Please do take care about the jsp file size limit of 64K [jsp file size limit](http://adam.goucher.ca/?p=166)

Comment: Uh no. There's no JSP file size limit. There is a 64K Java method limit. That limit is a byte code limit. The typical JSP file is mostly text, and that text does not count against the 64k method limit (since string constants are statically allocated to the class outside of the actual methods). So, yes, there are limits, I've hit them, but it's actually pretty difficult, and it's not as simple as having a 64k JSP file size.

Comment: Also, the limit applies to the container because the container is generating the .java file. I've seen Tomcat generate a .java file with a method size larger than 64k. Supposedly Glassfish and other containers take care to not generate a method that large. They can split the text into multiple methods.